# Twitter bootstrap - images not showing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website which works fine in Google Chrome, but not in other browsers (Firefox, Safari).

I'm having a problem with the following section of code:

```
        <div class="span2">
            <img src="./images/ads/karaoke.png" />
            <br><br><br>
            <img src="./images/ads/euros.png" />
            <br><br><br><br>
            <img src="./images/ads/parties.png" />
            <br><br><br><br>
            <img src="./images/ads/traleeDynamos.png" />
        </div>
```

As you can see, I'm displaying 4 images along the right hand side of the site. But the images won't render in Firefox!!!

What am I doing wrong?

The images show up in Firebug and when I hover over the  in Firebug, I can see the correct image. But it simply will not appear on the page.

I'd really appreciate someone looking at the code.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: works fine here, maybe try clearing your cache?

Comment: Tried clearing cahce - didn't work. I'm on a Mac. I have the same problem on Linux. Just checking Windows now.

Comment: i see the images in chrome, ff12 and safari 5.5.....what browser versions do u see this problem in? what os?  ah. on ff11....idk man. upgrade!

Comment: @Eamorr: just tried Firefox 12, works too.

Comment: Mmm. This is very fishy. It works in IE for me too. But not on Safari and Firefox on a Mac.

Comment: Make also sure that you do not have a plugin such as adblock enabled on the browser. It may think that the images are just ads and block them.

Comment: @Eamorr By the way, i know its something dumb but if you have adblocker installed in your FF installation make sure that that is not blocking the images, since they are coming from an /ads/ folder they were being blocked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the bootstrap [documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html):

> **Requires HTML5 doctype**
>
> Bootstrap makes use of HTML elements and CSS properties that require
>   the use of the HTML5 doctype. Be sure to include it at the beginning
>   of every Bootstrapped page in your project.

Currently you have:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 //EN">
```

As a doctype, so fix that, validate and try again to see if it works.

Comment: @Eamorr images are coming up for me now in FF3.6.17, try to clear your cache.

Comment: @Eamorr also coming up in IE8, Chrome16 and Safari.

Answer (score 4):

I can't replicate what you're seeing, but I don't have Firefox 11, however, a few things: the markup on that page is seriously outdated. Ditch <center> element, etc, and get rid of all the deprecated elements. Then validate the markup and styles. I noticed your first img has a closing </img> element... that's not valid and I'm willing to bet it's what's causing your issue(s).

Remember, validation is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is not showing in firefox and it is meant to take the full width of your browser, make sure you add the class="container-fluid"