# Mysteriously hidden images in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Short Summary**

Images are mysteriously disappearing from my pages when using bootstrap

**Problem**

I'm a little late to the game, but I figured it'd be a good time to really start learning bootstrap, so I fired up the less version and started customizing and getting some themes out there.

The issue I'm now facing is that images on the page don't always appear. I can confirm they're being loaded into the page, it's just that the element has it's display property set to none. If I toggle the image display in firebug, the image will display properly. Please see the attached firebug outputs

[image: The hidden dom element]
[image: Styles around the image]

**UPDATE**

After trying this in chrome, I received even more bizarre results. I don't know if this is me not using bootstrap properly or what. Basically the nav bar height keeps changing, and the positioning is ignored for the Login and Register buttons, unlike in firefox

[image: too tall]
[image: correct height, but buttons are off]

Here is an updated fiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/sw6v3gjy/**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ URL::route('home') }}">
                <img alt="commission cafe" src="path/to/my/image.gif"/>

            </a>
            <h1 class="navbar-text">Commission Caf&eacute;</h1>
            <br />
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for artists"/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
            </form>

        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 co-navbar-links pull-right">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Other</a>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Browse</a>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Trending</a>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Other</a>
                <span class="login-dropdown-span dropdown">
                    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
                        <span id="login-dropdown" class="btn-login-dropdown">Login</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ui class="dropdown-menu" style="padding:15px 5px;" role="menu" aria-labeledby="login-dropdown">
                        <form id="login-form">
                            <li>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="login-email"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="login-password"/>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="login-btn" name="login">Submit</button>
                            </li>
                        </form>
                    </ui>
                </span>
                <button onclick="location.href='{{ URL::route('registration.page') }}'" class="btn-register btn btn-default" type="button">Register</button>
            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You say images are disappearing but you haven't given us a fiddle with the image problem?

Comment: I can't understand the relation between the image problem, the css code in this question (there's no img styles), and the fiddle you provide (there isn't navbar in it). Please, could you clarify a little?

Comment: @Arkana I'll post an updated fiddle tonight, I think I screwed up the last one. Sorry about that

Comment: Fiddle updated, let me know if you're still confused. I know I'm having a little difficulty in trying to explain this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a definitive answer, but I found the issue had to do with the GIF image I was using. For some reason, bootstrap really doesn't like that. I used a PNG and now everything works perfect. I'll continue to do more research into what causes this issue with GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to use the HTML5 doctype at the beginning of each page.  Check out this previous question and let us know if this works out.

Fingers crossed!

[Twitter bootstrap - images not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362093/twitter-bootstrap-images-not-showing)

Comment: Alas, the doctype is on every page: <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Can you try in Chrome to see if it is something that is specific to Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I think the height of the parent div is the cause of this though I'm not sure until you can provide a jsfiddle of your page.

Try adding this to your css:

```
.navbar-brand    {
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot and provide a jsfiddle as well. Thanks! Any idea why it would be intermittent? Why thing I did notice was that when firebug was open, the image always appeared, and when firebug was closed, the image only sometimes appeared.

Comment: Firebug is a code viewer and bug checker and does not really relate with the page's style properties so that is one weird issue you got there

Comment: Exactly, that's why it's so weird. I wonder if when it's doing it's DOM scanning if that "nudges" something in the right way. It definitely impacts the viewport properties.

Comment: Do add the codes in jsfiddle. I'm quite intriqued by this

Comment: Here's the fiddle. Hope I got in what you were looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/brainbolt/52VtD/4/ . On the other hand, this fix didn't work I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

This [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/GCzNsJj0vY) can be your starting point to solve your problem. It follows all [bootstrap rules regarding navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) and looks like your example (if I got it right).

It is hard to explain what's wrong with your code in detail, but there are some minor differences to how it should be used or simply little bugs:

- Within the `navbar` you should not use `row`
- You have a tag `ui` which should be `ul`

Also notice what is documented about the [brand image](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image):

> Replace the navbar brand with your own image by swapping the text for an `<img>`. Since the `.navbar-brand` has its own padding and height, you may need to override some CSS depending on your image.

Comment: You've definitely got me on the right track, but the issue persists. Here is an updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sw6v3gjy/. I do want to add again that if the firefox panel is open, this issue never happens. It's very strange

Comment: Update: Tried it with a placeholder image from placehold.it and that never seems to have the issue occur. It's only with the gif image I'm using.